# What would be the best way to work with Server-side postbacks and jquery's animations?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, updatepanel, jquery-animate

What I want is something that tricks me everytime:

I'm writing an application just the way I use to:

some `<asp:LinkButtons>` (or normal buttons), loading content in Panels using some `<asp:UpdatePanel>` to do the ajaxy things..

How can I combine this with jquery's animations like `fade()`, `slide()`, `.animate()`, execute the animations AND load the server-side contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooking up the PageRequestManager's `beginRequest` and `endRequest` events you could do jQuery animations in between whilst the page content is reloading.

The flow would be something like this:

```
function beginRequestHandler(){
    $('#loadingDiv').fadeIn(); //show the loading div when the update panel is posting back.
} 

function endRequestHandler(){
    $('#loadingDiv').fadeOut(); //hide the loading div once the response is received.
}
```

Read more about it on [MSDN: beginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) | [MSDN: endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx)

Comment: The code itself didn't worked.. But the provided links solved the issue. Thank you

Comment: Hey f0x would you help me one more time please? I took everything on the code (first link) and placed it on a MasterPage / ChildPage structure, and it just does the postback and not the client-side scripts... Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Vitor, the above code was just an example of an implementation of the handlers. if you want to put your code in http://pastebin.com/ ill have a look or otherwise update your original post. Regards.